# PHP Error in PT Field Pack - Pill: "Array to string conversion Filename: fieldpack/ft.fieldpack_pill.php"

Tags: php-errors, field-pack

I'm not sure if I'm only just noticing this error, or if it just came up from some reason...

EE v2.7.2
PT Field Pack v2.1.1

**The Error:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message: Array to
>   string conversion
>  Filename: fieldpack/ft.fieldpack_pill.php
>   Line Number: 132

If I comment out line 132 in fieldpack/ft.fieldpack_pill.php the error goes away, and the fieldtype *seems* to work just fine:

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this? Is commenting the line out going to cause other problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this issue too on same installation. I had installed a new fieldtype (Plate Picker), which uses the `$settings['options']` array too to store the field_type settings. Problem is that P&T pill assumes all values inside `$settings['options']` are string values, but with my new field_type they are not.

I didn't dig deeper into EE Fieldtypes to find out what's the default way to store field_type options, so I don't know exactly who should fix this.

Instead of completely commenting out the line, you should be able to fix this by adding an extra line of code on line 130:

```
foreach($settings['options'] as $name => $label)
{
    if (is_array($label)) continue; // Added

    if ($r !== '') $r .= "\n";
    $r .= $name;
    if ($name !== $label) $r .= ' : '.$label;
    if (isset($settings['default']) && $settings['default'] == $name) $r .= ' *';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Field Pack gives you the option to specify a name and value pair, so in your field you could set:

```
[value] : [name]
```

which might equate to say

```
1 : Yes
0 : No
```

This would then display in your pill field as a Yes/No button, but allow you to use the value instead of the name in your template logic. eg.

```
{if pill_field == '1'}
```

The code you've commented out looks like its doing some checking on your field values, and *I think* its saying if the name and label are not identical, return the data in the format

```
$name : $label
```

So to answer your question, commenting this line out probably will have an impact on how the field works.

We use the field pack a lot but haven't come across this. I'd say its less likely to be an issue in the ft.fieldpack_pill.php file though.

What have you set as the default values in the field?